# Display Hyper-V vSwitch configuration in Powershell

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, virtual-machines, hyper-v, vswitch

Is there a way to display the full settings of a specific Hyper-V vSwitch using Powershell? I'm trying to configure port-mirroring from the vSwitch to the Destination vNIC on a VM and so I've set the vSwitch as the mirror Source but I want to be able to check that the setting has been applied.

OS is Windows Server 2012 R2

Thanks

Comment: For future uses of powershell, check this command: `Get-Command | Where-Object {$_.Source -eq 'Hyper-V'}`, this will list you all commands related to source `Hyper-V` (and you can, of course, change Hyper-V to whatever you like to know)

Comment: @Lenniey You can even avoid the UUoP `Get-Command -Module 'Hyper-V'`.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you need:

```
get-vmswitch | select *
```

Comment: Thanks. That is pretty useful but it doesn't give me exactly what I need. I want to find out if a vSwitch is configured as a port mirroring source or not.

Comment: [This post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2015/10/16/setting-up-port-mirroring-to-capture-mirrored-traffic-on-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine/) has some info about port mirroring and PowerShell.  I don't have anything like this set up, so I can't give you anything specific.